# TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable using PIL

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, ngrok, streamlit, image-classification

I'm trying to develop a web application on google colab. I want to make a image classifier using my model, which I previously trained, in this web application. When I select an image to be classified from browser in the web application, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable.
```

my code block:

```py
file = st.file_uploader("Please upload an image(png) file", type=["png"])
def import_and_predict(_image_data, model):
    size = (299,299)
    _image = ImageOps.fit(_image_data , size , Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = np.asarray(_image)
    img_reshape = _image[np.newaxis,...]
    prediction = model.predict(img_reshape)
    # image = image.convert('RGB')
    # st.image(image, channels='RGB')
    return prediction
if file is None:
    st.text("Please upload an image file !")
else:
    _image = Image.open(file)
    st.image(_image , use_column_width=True)
    prediction = import_and_predict(_image, model)
    class_names=['Cat','Dog']
    string="predict:" +class_names[np.argmax(predictions)]
    st.success(string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to do the reshape operation on the original Image object, when you should be doing it on the image array. Change this line:

```
img_reshape = _image[np.newaxis,...]
```

to:

```
img_reshape = img[np.newaxis,...]
```

and you should be good.